# Requesting to up vote in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, upvotes

Recently I faced situations when my questions were answered by certain users, but none of them upvoted the question. I've got an idea to comment under their answers and ask for an up vote, but I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Is it OK to ask for upvotes?

Comment: Technically, you can - there's no filter to prevent you from doing it. But such comments may get flagged, and it's pretty lame to do this. Don't worry about votes, just continue providing good content and they will come.

Comment: It's generally frowned upon as it makes it seem like you're here for the rep rather than helping others.

Comment: I was not in hunger of rep. But still I may feel to have votes that discussion

Comment: Assuming you are referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45688246/1889329), then frankly, don't complain. It's the average, low-quality contribution, that should be down- and close-voted (I just did). It's wasting lots of space (and bandwidth) for a useless screenshot, and then omits **vital** details. Asking for an up-vote for a clearly down-vote-worthy question will only attract down-votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact the your question got answered, doesn't mean that it should be upvoted.

If other users thought your question is good and helpful, they might upvote, but you can't and shouldn't force someone to vote on a post.

I wouldn't waste much time on thinking about votes (both positive and negative), instead, focus on providing good content, and eventually you'll be rewarded accordingly.

Comment: Well. Then. I think this question can be helpful to many others. But still no one are up voting this .

Comment: @SoftTech The man known to sometimes write useful answers doesn't always get a vote either: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+score%3A0+is%3Aa so don't assume up votes are a given

Comment: @rene That 0 could be a result of overflow.

Answer (score 8):

### No.

**Don't leave spammy comments on posts asking/begging for people to upvote.**

I've cleared out *hundreds* of these old comments over the past few days, and it makes me very upset when I see *new* ones getting posted. Users who get into a *habit* of doing this will be sternly warned, and if that doesn't take, very likely suspended. This practice needs to stop.

Votes should be based solely on the merits of a post, not whether you like someone or if they asked you nicely to vote on it.

There is no evidence that our users simply "forget" to vote on quality content, nor that there are a large number of users with vote privileges who don't know about their existence. If people thought your contributions were worth voting up, they would do so.